# How many solutions are there to the equation $na\equiv _m0$ for $0\leq a <m$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm reading trough a proof that the number of (group) homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}_n\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_m$ is $$\text{gcd}(n, m),$$
and this is the only step that I'm not understanding, namely, that the number of solutions to the equation $na\equiv _m0$ for $0\leq a <m$ is $\text{gcd}(n,m)$.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you figure out which values of $a \in \Bbb Z$ will satisfy $na \equiv_m 0$? Try an example. I'd recommend $m = 8, n = 12$.

Answer (score 0):

Write $n a \cong 0 \pmod{m}$ as 
$$  na = k m  \text{.}  $$
If $n$ and $m$ have a common factor, $d$, this reduces to $(n/d)a = k(m/d)$, equivalently a congruence with a smaller modulus
$$  (n/d)a \cong 0 \pmod{m/d}  $$
Then there is a solution in each of the $d$ copies of the interval of length $m/d$ in the interval of length $m$.  (In other words, the $d$ copies are $[a]$, $[a]+m/d$, $[a]+2m/d$, $\dots$, $[a]+(d-1)m/d$, where $[a]$ is the least nonnegative residue congruent to $a$ modulo $m/d$.)  Therefore, there are $d = \gcd(m,n)$ solutions.

Comment: `\equiv`, not `\cong`....

Comment: @ArturoMagidin : Modular congruences are **congruences**.

Comment: Yes, but the usual symbol is $\equiv$ (`\equiv`), not $\cong$ (`\cong`)...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin : Not for the first half of my life, and I will never support the wrong notation for congruences.

Comment: Well, it will be a lesser part of your life as time goes on... this is more of a problem with the nomenclature Knuth chose for the mathematical symbols, not for the symbols themselves. The three lines has a much longer genealogy than the other symbol, which is usually used for “isomorphism” in algebra. But different strokes for different folks...

Comment: @EricTowers Are you aware of anyone else that uses $\,a\cong b\,$ vs. the standard $\,a\equiv b\,$ for congruences in $\,\Bbb Z?\ \ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque : Yes.  It was the standard notation in pretty much everything I read up to the 90s.  This does roughly coincide with the transition from overstriking an equal sign with a tilde on a typewriter giving way to obviously wrong notation by TeX users, so Arturo's reference to Knuth is likely relevant.

Comment: I've read thousands of papers in number theory and algebra  in that period and earlier and I don't recall seeing such usage. I suspect it is quite rare. Do you have any links? The $\equiv$ notation goes back to the introduction of integer congruences by Gauss in  *Disq. Arith.* where he wrote "Numerorum congruentiam hoc signo, $\equiv$, in posterum denotabimus, modulum ubi opus erit in clausulis adiungentes, $-16\equiv 9\ \ ({\rm mod}.\, 5),\ -7\equiv 15\ \ ({\rm mod}.\, 11)$", See [here](https://la.wikisource.org/wiki/Pagina:Gauss,_Carl_Friedrich_-_Werke_(1870).djvu/20) for the scanned page.

Comment: An English translation is "Henceforth we shall designate congruence by the symbol $\,\equiv$, joining to it in parentheses the modulus when necessary to do so; e.g. ..."